# Use icns file as an image in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage

Is there a way to use an icns file as the image source for I guess a `UIImage`? Or pick out one of the representations and resize?

`NSImage` does not seem to be available in cocoa-touch.

In particular I'd like to use them for drawing in the imageView part of a UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this and I see little benefit in doing so. It's best to just use the sizes that you need and ship them as individual images in your app. If you want to draw the images in a UITableViewCell, performance is an important aspect and resizing images won't be fast.

If you really need images in many different sizes and really don't want the best performance by including images for each size, you could use a PDF to make use of vector graphics. There is a nice article about this technique: http://mattgemmell.com/2012/02/10/using-pdf-images-in-ios-apps/

Honestly, don't try to use .icns files in your iOS app. It's just a container for images of different sizes and resizing is not a good idea, anyway. Either include individual images for any size you need or use vector graphics using a PDF file.